# Is this Kansai dialect or standard Japanese: 「いつもうちの坊がお世話になってます。」

Tags: kansai-ben

I heard this sentence in the anime Blue Exorcist: Kyoto Saga eps 2, I wonder if the word うち in the sentence is Kansai dialect or standard Japanese? I thought it was standard Japanese but I wasn't quite sure.

> 虎子(女): はじめまして竜士の母です。いつも**うち**の坊がお世話になってます。

Can you give me an example of how to tell the difference?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK うち in the sense of “my, our (household, company etc.)” is standard Japanese. Only the first person pronoun usage is dialectal.